# Replace string elements inside a tag

Tags: python

I have a few strings in the following format:

```
string = http://1.8.1.1:5000/student/<studentid>/student_details/<rollnumber>
```

and 2 variables

```
x="myid"
y="myrollnumber"
```

What I want is replace 1st instance of <...> with variable x and second instance of <....> with variable y. It should not depend on what I have inside <> tags. Any string with that format should be replaced by x and y in their respective positions. The resulting output should look like:

```
string=http://1.8.1.1:5000/student/myid/student_details/myrollnumber
```

Comment: Have you tried something or are you just looking for an easy solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do like this,

```
>>> S = 'http://1.8.1.1:5000/student/<studentid>/student_details/<rollnumber>'
>>> import re
>>> k = re.sub(r'<.*?>', '{}', S)
>>> k
'http://1.8.1.1:5000/student/{}/student_details/{}'
>>> x="myid"
>>> y="myrollnumber"
>>> k.format(x, y)
'http://1.8.1.1:5000/student/myid/student_details/myrollnumber'
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if I understood correctly but this might be a solution:

```
string = "http://1.8.1.1:5000/student/%s/student_details/%s"%(x,y)
```

Let's put this inside a function:

```
def foo(studentID, rollNumber):
    string = "http://1.8.1.1:5000/student/%s/student_details/%s"%(studentID, rollNumber)
    return string
```

Is this helpful enough?
Let me know...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `replace`:

```
string = "http://1.8.1.1:5000/student/<studentid>/student_details/<rollnumber>"
x="myid"
y="myrollnumber"

newString = string.replace("<studentid>",x).replace("<rollnumber>",y)
```

In a function:

```
def changeString(studentid,rollNumber):
    newString = string.replace("<studentid>",studentid).replace("<rollnumber>",rollNumber)
    return newString
```